# Button Click to call login popup for validation

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a form that requires login validation as in when the user submits the form a popup with username/password will come up and only authorized user can submit the form. Is this possible in ADF? I dont want to traverse to another form or page, also once validated the page should not get refreshed. In case invalid user then can be redirected to an error page

Answer (score 0):

You must have write code in manageBean because you have access to data-base for check password and user name.